# Why is my char* in the loop assigned with a string but afterwards is "(null)" ? Compiler-Bug?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, pointers

I have a problem, on accessing data I've just set in my program: the computer says that some of my `char*` are `(null)`, which actually cannot be - please see my code snippet:

Because my code is way bigger I'm going to break it down into a more simple source code:

```
[...]

// in this loop I fill my array with strings
for(theChildren_It = theChildren.begin(); theChildren_It != theChildren.end();theChildren_It++,noOfStrings++)
{
   strings[noOfStrings] = (char*) malloc(400);
   strcpy(strings[noOfStrings],(*theChildren_It)->Name().c_str());

   // Debug output
   FILE *out = fopen("[...]/Debugtext","a+");
   fprintf(out, "INSIDE the loop: %i - %s -- %s\n", noOfStrings, (*theChildren_It)->Name().c_str(), strings[noOfStrings]);
   fclose(out);
}

// here I check the very first entry
FILE *asdf = fopen("[...]/Debugtext","a+");
fprintf(asdf, "OUTSIDE the loop: %i - %s -- %s\n", noOfStrings, (*theChildren.begin())->Name().c_str(), strings[0]);
fclose(asdf);

[...]
```

After running the program, the Debugtext is filled with lines like:

```
INSIDE the loop: 0 - ObjectA -- ObjectA
INSIDE the loop: 1 - ObjectB -- ObjectB
INSIDE the loop: 2 - ObjectC -- ObjectC


OUTSIDE the loop: 2 - ObjectA -- (null)
```

I hope it's not too less code that I've posted to understand, but I don't want to make it too complex.

Well I'm not sure why this is happening - this routine is running clean for 90% of the cases (means: most of the times it's running with `OUTSIDE the loop: 2 - ObjectA - ObjectA`). You could say the input is always the same - that's why I thought maybe there is a compiler error.

Has anyone an idea why this happens?

Kind Regards

Comment: You should never say "compiler bug" - doubt yourself and your code first, last, and always.  C/C++ compilers have been around for decades.  Any strange behavior you encounter is more likely to be your mistake or misunderstanding.

Comment: Why are you even using C-style `char *`, `malloc`, `printf` etc in what is apparently meant to be a C++ program ?

Comment: @PaulR because afterwards it will be used by a `.c`-based-GUI

Comment: Outside the loop, noOfStrings has gone up, should be reset for accessing the same string that you modified

Comment: @CashCow I call this function with the parameter `char* strings[400]`, isn't this call by reference ?

Comment: You do the check directly after the loop? There's no code between the loop and the check?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes there is no other code between for loop and "Print outside loop"

Comment: Are none of the strings longer than 399 characters ? Are there not more than 400 strings ?

Comment: @duffymo That entirely depends on your compiler and your level of experience. If you are a beginner/semi-experienced, then it is indeed unlikely that you will find compiler bugs. If you are a veteran with in-depth, nerdy knowledge of all the dirty details in the C standard, you do find compiler bugs now and then. More likely to happen when using less well-known compilers.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker - You were right, I had a bit more than 400 Strings,  after expanding the # of entries it's working again. Still I find this confusing - when I check the first entries and not the last, they shouldn't even realize what happens. I'd like to close this thread if you make this as an answer

Comment: @Lundin: True, but even experts are not going to claim to have discovered a compiler bug without first doing a very extensive and in-depth appraisal of their own code first (much, much more than the OP has done here).

Comment: @user3085931 You had more than 400 strings, or one string with more than 399+1 characters? You allocate room for 400 _characters_ not 400 strings.

Comment: @Lundin it's an array of 400 `char*` which wasn't big enough, there were a bit more entries

Comment: Writing beyond the end of an array results in [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and there's no way of knowing what will happen.

Comment: @user3085931 That doesn't make any sense. `strings[]` has to be an array of character pointers, with size <= `theChildren.size()`. For each such char pointer in that array, you allocate 400 _bytes_ which the pointer points at. The size of a char* is not 1 byte.

Comment: @Lundin for every entry in my `char*` array I'm allocating space for 400 chars - maybe the number 400 is confusing - I  also give the `char* strings[400]` as parameter

Comment: @user3085931 Ah ok :) Good old magic numbers...

Comment: @Lundin - I rest my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful with buffer overruns when using fixed-size arrays. You have two hard-coded upper bounds :

- the max. length of a string is 399 characters due to `malloc(400)`
- the max. number of strings is 400 due to `char* strings[400]`

When either of those limits are exceeded, a buffer overrun happens, and you overwrite memory beyond the buffer's bounds. This can have all kinds of nasty and unexpected effects (it's undefined behavior). Including the behavior that you observe (the first entry of the `strings` array could have been overwritten with zeroes eg.).